# VS Code debugger cannot "step" for .NET Console App

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm using VS code to write a simple .NET console application. Here's a look at my app's entry point:

`Program.cs`:

```
using System;

namespace MyApp
{
  class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("test");
      Console.WriteLine("another test");
    }
  }
}
```

I set a breakpoint on the line that reads, `Console.WriteLine("test")`, and start VS Code's debugger. The debugger highlights the line I've selected once it reaches that point in execution. Great. Then I press the "step over" button.

Expected behavior: `test` will be written to the debug console and the debugger will advance to the next line of code.

Actual behavior: `test` is not written to the debug console. Execution stops immediately and the console reads: `The program '[3803] MyApp.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

I re-launch my simple application without changing anything. The debugger once again stops at `Console.WriteLine("test")`. This time I press F5 to continue running. Again, nothing is written to the console and I am shown that the app `has exited with code 0`.

I re-launch the app, again. When the debugger stops at `Console.WriteLine("test")`, I *un-set* my breakpoint and press F5. `test` is written to the console, followed by `another test`, and the application finishes (`with code 0`, of course). I've found that the debugger will break at a later breakpoint, but **I must un-set each breakpoint as it is reached** (and then continue running / press F5)... otherwise the application stops running and I'm shown the same, simple `exited with code 0` message. Un-setting a breakpoint makes no difference for "stepping over" / "stepping into" - those commands do not seem to work at all.

For what it's worth, I'm working on a MacBook running macOS Big Sur on an Apple M1 chip (I have no idea if this is useful information). Here is more detailed information about my workspace configuration:

`MyApp.soln`:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.808.8
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MyApp", "MyApp\MyApp.csproj", "{D12824DE-83AF-4C7B-B5C2-C6CB1B9554C6}"
EndProject
Global
  GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|anycpu = Debug|anycpu
    Release|anycpu = Release|anycpu
  EndGlobalSection
  GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
    {D12824DE-83AF-4C7B-B5C2-C6CB1B9554C6}.Debug|anycpu.ActiveCfg = Debug|anycpu
    {D12824DE-83AF-4C7B-B5C2-C6CB1B9554C6}.Debug|anycpu.Build.0 = Debug|anycpu
    {D12824DE-83AF-4C7B-B5C2-C6CB1B9554C6}.Release|anycpu.ActiveCfg = Release|anycpu
    {D12824DE-83AF-4C7B-B5C2-C6CB1B9554C6}.Release|anycpu.Build.0 = Release|anycpu
  EndGlobalSection
  GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
    HideSolutionNode = FALSE
  EndGlobalSection
  GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
    SolutionGuid = {8A94F55D-F55A-450C-A412-10554B4B7799}
  EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

`MyApp.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

`launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/MyApp/bin/Debug/net5.0/MyApp.dll",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/MyApp/bin/Debug/net5.0",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "console": "internalConsole"
    }
  ]
}
```

`tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MyApp/MyApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MyApp/MyApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MyApp/MyApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get VS Code's debugger to work as expected?

Comment: I doubt there's a way for anyone here to say for sure what's wrong. The first thing you should check though is what build configuration you're using. Default is for there to be a "Debug" and a "Release". Trying to debug the latter can result in some odd behavior like what you're seeing, due to optimizations the compiler makes, which causes the line-by-line statements in your program to not correspond precisely to the instructions being executed while debugging.

Comment: @PeterDuniho that's a great idea. I've seen what you're talking about while debugging WPF apps in Visual Studio. I initially made this solution in Visual Studio for Mac and I edited the .soln and .csproj files until I managed to run it in VS Code... Until now, I've relied on Visual Studio to maintain those particular files. It's very likely that I've somehow messed something up. I'll take another look tomorrow and I'll return with my findings. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterDuniho the build-configuration-question was unfortunately a dead end, but I think I've determined that there's a compatibility issue with the M1 chip. I ran `dotnet new console` to start from scratch and the problem persisted. I followed this same process on an older Mac with an Intel chip, and debugging worked as expected. My target framework was .NET 5.0 in both cases. The system architecture is the only difference that I know to exist between the two tests that I ran. I suspect that I'll have to use my old Mac until an SDK is released that is fully compatible with the M1 chip. Thanks!

Comment: Any luck since you asked? I'm seeing something similar on an M1 MacBook now.

Comment: @ruffin I never solved the issue for my M1 Mac. I finished the project on my older, Intel-based Mac and haven't had a need to revisit the problem since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the .NET 5.0 SDK is not fully compatible with the new Apple M1 chip. I followed the process below on two Macs: one with an Intel chip and the other with an M1 chip:

1. Install the [.NET 5.0 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download).
2. Run `dotnet new console` to create a new console application.
3. Create a file, `.vscode/launch.json`, open it, and click the "Add Configuration" button. Select `.NET: Launch .NET Core Console App`. Update all placeholder-text in the file according to the structure of your project. You'll also need to create a `.vscode/tasks.json` file like the one that I included in my original post.
4. Attempt to debug the project in VS Code.

Running and debugging the application with this launch configuration works as expected on my Intel-chip-Mac, but not on my M1-chip-Mac. Looks like I'll be working from my old Mac until an M1-compatible .NET SDK is released.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. When a debugger is enabled the program exists abruptly. Any updates on the M1 compatible  .Net SDK's?

Comment: No updates, regrettably.